# Odoo 12 ./odoo-bin does not run, produce a odoo.sql_db error

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, odoo

i have followed a tutorial and installed odoo+postgres
when i try to run in my linux terminal ./odoo-bin command, i get this error:

```
2019-09-15 08:48:30,765 5126 ERROR test werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 409, in app
return self.app(e, s)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 128, in 
application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in 
application_unproxied
result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1320, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1473, in dispatch
ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
File "/home/blink22/Desktop/odoo-nada/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in 
__getitem__
return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'ir.http' - - -
2019-09-15 08:48:54,130 5126 ERROR test odoo.sql_db: bad query: b"SELECT latest_version 
FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base'"
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base...
                                       ^
```

is the error related to which DB user i am using? or it is something else??

here is my bash commands that i used to install that:
https://github.com/mah007/OdooScript/blob/master/odoo_dev.sh

Comment: It says it right there. The Table `ir_module_module ` does not exist.

Comment: Shouldn't you supply any arguments to the command?

Answer (score 5):

however you're question is not very clear but I can assume that this issue is occurred because you didn't initiate your database before running the server.

you need first init your db (and the logs shows that its name is `test`):

`$ ./odoo-bin -i base -d test`

the you can start the Odoo server as usual.

`$ ./odoo-bin`

if this is a development environment then start fresh with a new database.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue while running OdooV13 in ubuntu20. I have missed to include some addons under addons path, because of which "**base**" module was not found.

I was able to resolve my issue by including base module folder in addons path and run server with "**-i base -d test**" to initialize my database, as suggested by *Ahmed Magdy*.